# SQL Server : multiple rows values into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a scenario where in a SQL Server database based on status and id I have to group the rows and display the count. I was trying but I am getting values in separate separate rows like below

```
select  
    req_id as bid, status,
    (case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as accept,
    count(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as rejected,
    (case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as noResp 
from 
    temp_allo
group by 
    req_id, status
```

Result is

```
bid status  accept  rejected    noResp
--------------------------------------
1     1       1        1        0
2     1       1        1        0
3     1       1        1        0
2     2       0        2        0
3     2       0        1        0
```

(status is only for reference)

but I need result like this:

```
bid     accept  rejected    noResp
-----------------------------------
1       1         0          0
2       1         2          0
3       1         1          0
```

I got many samples from stackoverflow I tried `MAX()`, `SUM()`, `CASE` but I couldn't make it work.

Please suggest..

Comment: How to have rejected=0 for bid=1, isn't it some problem with logic ?

Comment: this is a count based on status how many people rejected its extracted from database entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are pivoting on the status, therefore I propose that it should not appear in the `GROUP BY` list.  Instead, aggregate over the `req_id` and then use `MAX()` with your current `CASE` expressions.

```
select
    req_id as bid,
    max(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as accept,
    max(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as rejected,
    max(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as noResp
from temp_allo
group by req_id
```